# how to view date before 2 month early with four condition status

Tags: php, mysql

im try to using this function to check **if date less than 2 months from expiry date, it will show "expires soon"**, then **at the time of the expiration date, it will show "expired"**, **after the expiration date, it will show "completed"**, and lastly **more than one or two month after expiration date it will show "active"**. so it is wrong what am i doing? help me please to solve this.
Thank you!

```
<?php
    $today_date = date('Y-m-d');
    $expiry_date = $row->v_ExpiryDate;
    $timestamp = strtotime($expiry_date);
    $warning_days = 60;
    $seconds_diff = $warning_days * 24 * 3600; // taking 60 (days) * 24 (hours) * 3600 (seconds)
    $warning_timestamp = $timestamp - $seconds_diff;
    $warning_date = date('Y-m-d', $warning_timestamp);

    if ( $today_date < $warning_date){
        echo "Expired soon";
        } elseif ($today_date == $expiry_date) {
        echo "Expired!";
        } elseif ($today_date > $expiry_date) {
        echo "Completed";
        } else {
        echo "Active";
        }
?>
```

Comment: The `date()` function converts a timestamp into a formatted string. Your conditions are comparing strings, not timestamps.

Comment: Make sure that `$expiry_date` is really in the format of 'Y-m-d'.  I can’t test this right now, but I suggest `$timestamp = strtotime($row->v_ExpiryDate); $expiry_date = date('Y-m-d', $timestamp);`. That way you know you’re comparing strings that are formatted identically.

Answer (score 0):

You should compare `timestamps` instead of `strings`:

```php
<?php
    $today = strtotime("today");
    $expiry_date = $row->v_ExpiryDate;
    $expiry_timestamp = strtotime($expiry_date);
    $warning_days = 60;
    $seconds_diff = $warning_days * 24 * 3600; // taking 60 (days) * 24 (hours) * 3600 (seconds)
    $warning_timestamp = $expiry_timestamp - $seconds_diff;

    if ( $today < $warning_timestamp ){
        echo "Expired soon";
        } elseif ($today == $expiry_timestamp) {
        echo "Expired!";
        } elseif ($today > $expiry_timestamp) {
        echo "Completed";
        } else {
        echo "Active";
        }
?>
```